# Can't put an anchor in the right place

Tags: docusignapi

I'm trying to add an anchor to a xml document (word document), but its not working for some reason. I'm following https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/explore/features/stick-etabs, section Tab Placement Method 2: Auto-Place (Anchor Tagging). That is the result I'm having:

[image]

I tried to adjust anchorXOffset and anchorYOffset properties. I'm trying to put the sign after the "Yours sincerely" text:

```
request_hash = {
  'status'       => 'sent',
  'emailBlurb'   => 'eblurb',
  'emailSubject' => 'Hello, you have a contract file to be signed. Hurry up!',
  'documents'    => [
      {
          'name'        => file_name,
          'documentId'  => '1',
          'order'       => '1'
      }
  ],
  'recipients'   => {
    'signers' => [
      { # Employee
        'email'       => user_email,
        'name'        => user_name,
        'recipientId' => '2',
        "tabs"        => {
          "signHereTabs" => [{
            #"xPosition" => "120",
            #"yPosition" => "110",
            "anchorString": "SIGNED",
            "anchorXOffset": "1",
            "anchorYOffset": "0",
            "anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent": "true",
            "anchorUnits": "inches",
            "documentId" => "1",
            "pageNumber" => "11"
          }]
        }
      },
      { # The owner
        'email'       => ENV['manager_email'],
        'name'        => ENV['manager_name'],
        'recipientId' => '1',
        "tabs"        => {
          "signHereTabs" => [{
             #"xPosition" => "70",
             #"yPosition" => "500",
             "anchorString": "Yours sincerely",
             "anchorXOffset": "0",
             "anchorYOffset": "0",
             "anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent": "true",
             "anchorUnits": "inches",
             "documentId" => "1",
             "pageNumber" => "10"
         }]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest starting with a single word anchor string, eg "sincerely".

Also, remove "pageNumber" from the `signHereTabs` object. It shouldn't be used while you're using anchor text positioning.

Lastly, check out the [anchor text recipe](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/recipes/autoplace) for more information and a working example.